# Buscar en una lista con Linq a traves de reflexión

Tags: c#, linq, reflexión

Buenas comunidad haber si me podéis darme alguna idea sobre este tema. Estoy mirando de crear una función que al pasarle cualquier lista, el nombre de la propiedad y un valor me encuentre registros, seria lo siguiente:

```
public static object BuscarObjetoDynamicoEnLista(dynamic entitie, string column, string word)
    {
        List<dynamic> lista = (List<dynamic>)entitie;
                    
        if(lista.Count()> 0){
            PropertyInfo prop = lista.First().GetType().GetProperty(column, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            var valor = Convert.ChangeType(word.Trim(), prop.PropertyType);
            

            var item = lista.Where(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(x, null) == valor).FirstOrDefault();

            if (item != null) { return item; }                        
        }
        return null;
    }
```

De esta manera la variable entities es un IQueryable de cualquier tabla de la base de datos, el string column como podéis ver es por que propiedad de la entiti quiero buscar y por ultimo el word es el valor para poder hacer el where en linq.

El problema que tengo es que no me encuentra nada, le estoy pasando en column "Id" y en word  "8", en el listado existe un registro con Id = 8 y me dice que el item es null.

Comment: Buff..cada vez que veo `dynamic` se me eriza la piel. No has pensado mejor hacerlo con genericos?

Comment: Pikoh estoy haciendo `Convert.ChangeType()` esto me hace un convert del string al tipo de la propiedad que sea del objeto. Con genericos lo he intentado pero esto lo estoy haciendo por una importacion de un excel y quiero que me sirva para varias importaciones.

Comment: Ya, pero me temo que el problema es precisamente el ChangeType. Aunque te parezca que lo convierte al tipo, en realidad me parece que es un `object` de todas maneras. Si quieres confirmarlo, cambia la linea esta por `var item = lista.Where(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(x, null) == (int)valor).FirstOrDefault();` a ver si te encuentra asi el objeto. Los cambios de tipo en reflection son muy suyos, y no confio mucho en que lo soluciones

Comment: Una opcion para solucionarlo si sabes que no hay tipos complejos, es que hagas la comparacion con `ToString()` en ambos lados: `var item = lista.Where(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(x, null).ToString() == valor.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: Gracias Pikoh si de esa manera funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Al final por las pruebas que he realizado tal como me ha dicho @Pikoh lo he dejado de esta manera, publico la respuesta por si alguien la necesita o si bé alguna otra solución.

```
var valor = Convert.ChangeType(word.Trim(), prop.PropertyType);
            dynamic item = null;
            
            switch (prop.PropertyType.Name)
            {
                case "Int32":
                case "Int64":
                    item = (from d in lista where d.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(d, null) == (int)valor select d).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (item != null) { return item; }
                    break;
                case "DateTime":
                    item = (from d in lista where d.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(d, null) == (DateTime)valor select d).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (item != null) { return item; }
                    break;
                case "Double":
                    item = (from d in lista where d.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(d, null) == (double)valor select d).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (item != null) { return item; }
                    break;
                case "String":
                    item = (from d in lista where d.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(d, null).ToString() == word select d).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (item != null) { return item; }
                    break;
                case "Guid":
                    item = (from d in lista where d.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(d, null).ToString() == word select d).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (item != null) { return item; }
                    break;
            }
```

Lo que hago es coger el nombre del PropertyType y lo convierto a su propiedad mas que nada por si en los tipos de números, floats o datetimes la consulta en vez de ser igual tiene que ser mayor o menor que y cosas así.

Comment: Puedes mejorar el codigo con los patrones de c# 7. Sería algo asi: 
           `switch (valor)
            {
                case int a:
                    item = lista.Where(x => (int)x.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(x, null) == a).FirstOrDefault();
                    break;` Como ves, el `switch` se hace sobre la variable valor, y el propio `switch` se encarga de encajar con el tipo al definirlo como `case _tipo_ variable`, y asi no hay que hacerlo sobre el nombre del tipo

Comment: Perfecto @Pikoh mil gracais